# GTest Typed Test - Using

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to use 'MyType' from the base class in the 'DoesBlah' test below.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template <typename T>
struct MemberVariable
{
    T m_t;
};

struct Base : public ::testing::Test
{
    template <typename MemberType>
    using MyType = MemberVariable<MemberType>;
};

template <typename DerivedType>
struct Derived : public Base
{
};

typedef ::testing::Types<int, char> MyTypes;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(Derived, MyTypes);

TYPED_TEST(Derived, DoesBlah)
{
    MyType<TypeParam> test;
    test.m_t = (TypeParam)1;
    ASSERT_EQ(test.m_t, 1);
}
```

However, I get the following compilation error:

```
gti/specific/level/Test.t.cpp: In member function 'virtual void Derived_DoesBlah_Test<gtest_TypeParam_>::TestBody()':
gti/specific/level/Test.t.cpp:25:5: error: 'MyType' was not declared in this scope
     MyType<TypeParam> test;
```

I tried using TestFixture::MyType, typename TestFixture::MyType, but both did not work.

How can I get Derived to recognize that there's something called 'MyType'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some simplifications, the macro `TYPED_TEST(Derived, DoesBlah)` expands to something like:

```
template <typename TypeParam>
class Derived_DoesBlah_Test : public Derived<TypeParam>
{
private:
    typedef Derived<TypeParam> TestFixture;
    virtual void TestBody();
};
template <typename TypeParam>
void Derived_DoesBlah_Test<TypeParam>::TestBody()
```

So the `{}` block that follows is the function definition for a member of a template class which derives from `Derived<TypeParam>`.  The `typedef` for `TestFixture` is available, but it depends on the template parameter `TypeParam`, so it is considered a dependent type.  What's more, you want to access a template member of that dependent type.  So you need both the `typename` and `template` keywords:

```
{
    typename TestFixture::template MyType<TypeParam> test;
    test.m_t = (TypeParam)1;
    ASSERT_EQ(test.m_t, 1);
}
```

For more about dependent types and using the `typename` and `template` keywords in declarations and expressions, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).